# Long text (> 255 chars) truncated while importing and adding to existing table in MS Access 2013

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to import an excel spreadsheet using the below VBA code. Before bringing it in I am also deleting the current contents of the table.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM REBATE_PROG")
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "REBATE_PROG", filepath, True
```

The rebate_prog table already has fields defined as long text (which is the old memo field, as per my understanding) which should be able to store > 255 chars.

Is there a reason why Access would be truncating the contents?

Some of the things that I have tried, without success:

- Sorting the import file in descending on the length of the field which is truncating - for if excel looks at only a few top rows, it would import as Long text.
- Tried to update the "Text Format" for the field under Design View in table properties to Rich text from Plain, but for some reason Access doesn't allow me to make the change.

Is there a way I can import the excel spreadsheet without access truncating the fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncated Data when Importing from Excel to an Access Memo Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249753/truncated-data-when-importing-from-excel-to-an-access-memo-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way of fixing this issue. There might be other solutions out there as well but this one seemed to have worked for me the best. Below is a step by step of what I did:

1. **Manually creating an Access Table:** I went with manually creating the table structure in access 2013 and defining each data type for each field. On the field that I wanted to have >255 characters imported, I set this field data type as "Long text" and also selected the format to "Rich text".

*Note:* The structure I created for this table is exactly as it is in the file I intend on importing.

2. **Sorting Import File on Character length**: Next, I added a new field in the import file using `LEN()` function as `LEN(<Cell in the long text field>)`. And then used this field to sort all records in descending order and saved the file. I had to do this because Access while importing looks at a few top rows to determine how much data needs to be imported from the column (I learned this after going through a few forums).

*Note:* You could also create a VBA code which does the sorting in descending order for you right before importing, but I haven't executed that yet. If you do, please do share the code here!

3. **Import!**: Finally, use the code I provided below to truncate the table we manually created and insert the contents from excel into the table.

`DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM REBATE_PROG")
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "REBATE_PROG", filepath, True`

Answer (score 3):

Here's the fast trick I usually do against that kind of datatype issues.
(assuming your Excel file is not a monster):

1. In Excel, first add an empty column at the beginning (A), secondly select your whole sheet (click top-left), and then CTRL-C
2. In Access, create a new table using "table" button. Click top-left to select everything (there should be only one cell), and then CTRL-V
   Your data is there and your columns are created. 
   Check the columns where the long text is, it's probably Short Text and your data is truncated. Go in design mode on your table and change the field to LongText/Memo, change the format to rich text (to be sure it doesnt not hide after 254 chars) and save the table.
3. Delete all rows from your table
4. Repeat the copy/paste operation from Excel to your table

Your text should not be truncated anymore and you can use this table or a struct copy of it to make your further VBA imports in APPEND mode

Comment: I tried performing the above steps.. i wasn't able to change the format type to rich text.. and without it the suggested way doesnt seem to work. When I manually copy the excel data and paste it in the table - all the information comes in (non-truncated) as intended. But when I try to automate the import process using the VBA code mentioned in the initial question - the data is truncated like before. Any suggestions on what I can try next? If need be I can update the VBA code as well.. if that would fix the truncation.

Comment: OK, so with that step we have determined that the issue in not in Access but rather in the _TransferSpreadsheet _ command. There's something you can do: in your Excel sheet, on **first row**, for column(s) containing Long Text, check if the cell do contains a long text (>255 chars). If not, add a new first row with a long text for each long text column. That way  the importer will know that this column(s) contains long text and won't consider it short text for the rest of the file which I suspect to be the root cause of your problem

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I actually found an alternative which I just implemented a minute ago. Seems promising. I have updated the question with the solution that I implemented for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the long text was imported from Excel to Access 2016 but could not be fully seen.

Simply removing the '@' from the Format property in the table allowed the full field to be seen in the table.

Likewise, removing the '@' on a form text box displaying the long text, allowed the full field to be seen on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. I isolated the Long Text field so that I could add it using an Update instead of an Append.

So in my original pass, I appended the data from the linked Excel table into my access table. That didn't work as it truncated the Long Text. So what I did was remove the Long Text field from the Append query, and ran the Append for all other fields

Now my new records have Null for that Long Text field, and my existing records have Long Text. (I needed to do this because the Long Text may have changed, and I need to do an Update later in the loading routing if the current Long Text does not match the existing Long Text. (This is how I found this))

So, now I can do an Update to the records where the Long Text field is Null, and leave untouched the records that have Long Text. This enters the entire Long Text.

Later when I do a second Update of text that has changed, the database will see actual changes instead of the mistaken changes that I was getting due to the Append truncation.

Update is Good. Append is Bad

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple and easy solution to this problem. For example, some rows for Column A in worksheet #1 contains short texts and some rows for the same column has long texts. Make a copy of worksheet #1 as worksheet #2.

On worksheet #1, delete long-text rows for column A and keep only short-text rows.

On worksheet #2, delete short-text rows for column A and keep only long-text rows.

Now use the transfer spreadsheet command for workheet 1 and then for woeksheet #2.

```
Call DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet( _
    acImport, _
    acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
    strTableName, _
    strFullPathOfWorkbook, _
    True, _
    "WorkSheet_1!A1:Z1000)

Call DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet( _
    acImport, _
    acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
    strTableName, _
    strFullPathOfWorkbook, _
    True, _
    "WorkSheet_2!A1:Z1000)
```

I have tested this solution more than 100 times and it works perfectly. The trick is to divide columns with mixed short-text and long-text rows in two worksheets.
All other programmers have failed because majority of them ignored the fact that VBA cannot handle a mixed column with both short and long texts.

Comment: OP's solution of sorting spreadsheet rows so >255 data is first forces Access to recognize the column contains long text and treat the column as long text field. Fine as long as there is only the one field of long text. Same goes for this suggestion.