# How to create Memo with property as Rich Text using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

When i am importing excel sheet Using TransferSpreadsheet, it is not getting values with more than 255 characters. I have my table with Long Text still the problem persist. A quick search on this left me with making the field property to rich text.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE(F1 MEMO)"
```

Is there a way I can make the Field F1 rich text using the same query?

Comment: You can't do it directly when creating the table or field, you have to do it afterwards, see above.

Comment: check this also it helped me a lot. It give info why you get only 255 characters while importing or exporting the data from access. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249753/truncated-data-when-importing-from-excel-to-an-access-memo-field)