# Access 2016 Dropping field values during csv file import with VBA /SQL

Tags: sql, vba, csv, ms-access, import

I am importing a csv file into an Access table.  The problem I'm having is the import is dropping some values in the RefID field.  I'm not getting any type of error message.  The RefID field is formatted in the table as short text (255)

The SQL statement to import the file is as follows:

vSQL = "INSERT INTO [tbl_Stage] ([BATID], [AGNCY_NAM], [CNTRCTNBR], [REFID], [ISSDTE], [ISSUETIME], [VIOLT_CDE], [VIOLT_TYPE], [CTTNAMT], [ERACADMFEE], [RENTINGGPBR]) " & _
"SELECT [BATID], [AGNCY_NAM], [CNTRCTNBR], [REFID], [ISSDTE], [ISSUETIME], [VIOLT_CDE], [VIOLT_TYPE], [CTTNAMT], [ERACADMFEE], [RENTINGGPBR] " & _
"FROM [text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,);Database=V:\Accounting Process Support\Projects\In Work].[Mon Coll Rpt 09072021.csv]"

db.Execute vSQL, dbFailOnError

These are the values that are not being imported:

16-000139797
DY10200076*
DY10216425
16-000139796
16-000141342*
CL94630613*
CL94630670*
E116492922

These values are being truncated:
(Before)
024.0004379901*
024.0004386081*
024.0004386701*
(After)
24.0004
24.0004
24.0004

I thought by making the field as short text, it would import the values as is.  I need the complete value in the database.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at this question........

Comment: What number does Access show your for this?: `Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("tbl_Stage").Fields("REFID").Type` If it says 10, try `CStr()` to cast the CSV REFID value to string like `INSERT INTO [tbl_Stage] ([REFID]) SELECT CStr([REFID]) FROM ...` If the  `Debug.Print` shows you some number other that 10, what number is it?

Answer (score 0):

[From the Microsoft docs on importing from Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-excel-workbook-a1952878-7c58-47b1-893d-e084913cc958?correlationid=287ee85e-ff57-4f21-8da2-61cddaaa3457&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) (it appears that CSV has similar behavior):

> To avoid errors during importing, ensure that each source column
> contains the same type of data in every row. Access scans the first
> eight source rows to determine the data type of the fields in the
> table. We highly recommend that you ensure that the first eight source
> rows do not mix values of different data types in any of the columns.
> Otherwise, Access might not assign the correct data type to the
> column.

In other words, it appears to be seeing your values as floats and throwing away the others.

[There were some possible solutions here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249753/truncated-data-when-importing-from-excel-to-an-access-memo-field)